# How to get more detail of 'Access Denied'?

Tags: asp.net, exception

Currently one of my application is having issue with "Access Denied" when creating folder in their server. Since the server is not manage by me, I couldn't access to check on the permission issue and stuff.

I know this is all about permission issue. Everything works fine on my side.

I'm just think if there is any way I could squeeze more from this UnauthorizedAccessException so that I'm able to find what type of access denied issue it is. As in which user is not given the necessary permission, what permission is lacking and etc.

For now, this is the full Stack Trace but it doesn't help to know the root cause

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.File.Create(String path) at SampleProject.Code.ExceptionTest.btnTriggerEx_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Desktop 20150824\Desktop\Main\Programming\SampleTest\SampleProject\SampleProject\Code\ExceptionTest.aspx.cs:line 38

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Check the Message, HResult, Inner Exceptions and details in the thrown exception to begin with. I believe just stack trace won't help much.

Comment: catch the exception and wrap it with something more descriptive message or ask for a debug dump.